# Generate runnable LLVM IR from Julia script?

Tags: llvm, julia, llvm-ir

I am wondering how to convert Julia code into runnable LLVM IR(the *.ll file).

There is a command named `code_llvm` which can compile a Julia function into LLVM IR. But its result contains something like `%jl_value_t*` which seems to be an (hidden?) object type, and it doesn't look like pure LLVM IR.

Is there a way to generate runnable LLVM IR from Julia, so that I can run it with `lli xx.ll` (or do something else)?

Comment: I answered your question on the mailing list.

Comment: @lsaiah Thanks for your answer in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/g2-NYFyomfk

Comment: It might be worth marking this question as answered.

Comment: @isaiahNorton Hello, could you please write up a summary of the answer here on SO?

Comment: There have been some recent developments related to WebAssembly, which rely on closely-related functionality: https://nextjournal.com/sdanisch/wasm-julia (and see also discussion on the [Julia forum](discourse.julialang.org). I can't write up a full answer right now, but hopefully these links will get you going.

Answer (score 1):

The `code_llvm` function just shows the Function by default, but you can also have it print out a complete module:

```
open("file.ll", "w") do io
    code_llvm(io, +, (Int, Int); raw=true, dump_module=true, optimize=true)
end
```

This output (`file.ll`) is now valid to use with other llvm tools, such as `llc` and `opt`. However, since it's just the code for this one function, and assumes the existence of all the other code and data, it's not necessarily going to work with `lli`, so buyer beware.

If you want a complete system, you might be interested in the `--output-bc` flag to Julia, which will dump a complete object file in LLVM format. This is used extensively internally to build and bootstrap Julia. It's also wrapped into a utility tool at https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl to automate some of these steps.